# when will SetUnhandledExceptionFilter not work? e.g. stack corruptions?

Tags: exception, crash, crash-reports, crash-dumps

I would like to have my code create a dump for unhandled exceptions.
I'd thought of using the SetUnhandledExceptionFilter. But what are the cases when SetUnhandledExceptionFilter may not work as expected. For example what about stack corruption issues when, for instance, a buffer overrun occurs on stack?
what will happen in this case? are there any additional solutions which will always work?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using *SetUnhandledExceptionFilter* for quite a while and have not noticed any crashes/problems that are not trapped correctly.  And, if an exception is not handled somewhere in the code, it should get handled by the filter.  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) regarding the filter...

> After calling this function, if an exception occurs in a process that
>   is not being debugged, and the exception makes it to the unhandled
>   exception filter, that filter will call the exception filter function
>   specified by the lpTopLevelExceptionFilter parameter.

There is no mention that the above applies to only certain types of exceptions.

I don't use the filter to create a dump file because the application uses the Microsoft [WER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) system to report crashes.  Rather, the filter is used to provide an opportunity to collect two additional files to attach to the crash report (and dump file) that Microsoft will collect.

Here's an example of Microsoft's crash report dashboard for the application with module names redacted.

[image]

You'll see that there's a wide range of crash types collected, including, *stack buffer overrun.*

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure no other code calls the `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()` after you set it to your handler.

I had a similar issue and in my case it was caused by another linked library (ImageMagick) which called `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()` from its `Magick::InitializeMagick()` which was called just in some situations in our application. Then it replaced our handler with ImageMagick's handler.

I found it by setting a breakpoint on `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()` in gdb and checked the backtrace.